# Weaving in toString() implementation with AspectJ

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, tostring, dto

Trying to weave in a default toString() method for a large number of DTOs, using compile-time weaving only. The goal is to return a JSON representation using the Jackson library.

Followed the suggestions in [this article](http://invalidcodeexception.com/implementing-a-default-tostring-method-with-aspectj/), turned it into annotation-style aspect config, and ended up with the following code:

```
public @Aspect class JsonToStringAspect {
    private interface JsonToString {
        public String toString();
    }

    public static class JsonToStringImpl implements JsonToString {
        public String toString() {
            return SingletonJsonEncoder.toJsonString(this);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @DeclareParents(value = "com.mycompany.dto..*", defaultImpl = JsonToStringImpl.class)
    private JsonToString implementedInterface;
}
```

Running `javap` on the resulting classes shows that they implement the JsonToString interface, but there's no sign of the toString() method anywhere.

If I change the method name to something that doesn't collide with Object.toString() (e.g. toString2()), the method is truly added.

Any clues on how to overcome this? Maybe an `@Around` advice on a pointcut that intercepts the execution of java.lang.Object.toString(), only for children classes below package `com.mycompany.dto`? Or a way to force the mixin to happen?

Comment: Not what you are looking for I know, but in general I suggest AOP should be reserved for architectural concerns like transactions, retry strategies, authorization, auditing, etc. and not more mundane things like a one-liner `toString()` method. Obviously it helps keep your `toString()` methods [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) but its also a bit of non-obvious "magic" that makes a codebase more complicated.

Comment: @SingleShot There's a big difference between load-time weaving and compile-time weaving. I share your suggestion if placed in the context of load-time weaving. But compile-time weaving (which is what this question is about) is a perfectly valid and sane way to keep your codebase DRY. Moreover, I don't think your statement is valid at all. "Magic" is much more dangerous when performing state-changing operations (e.g. transactional advices) than a simple toString() method which is (or should be) read-only. So following your argument about "complication", AOP should never be used at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your scenario and could replicate the behavior, I also tried combinations of `@DeclareMixin` instead of `@DeclareParent` and could not get that to work either. What worked for me though is to use native aspectj this way:

```
public aspect JsonToStringAspect {
    private interface JsonToString {}
    declare parents: com.mycompany.dto.* implements JsonToString;

    public String JsonToString.toString() {
        return "Overridden String through JsonToStringAspect";
    }
}
```

I am guessing that this may not be feasible using `@AspectJ` and may be possible only through native aspects.

Comment: Biju, thanks. You are right, it works with native AspectJ notation. Can you remove the toString2() method from your example, as it's not relevant and can confuse others? Then I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks.