# How to add an object (which is not instantiated by spring) to bean container for AOP?

Tags: java, spring, aop

**Aspect**  which changes toString()'s return value to it's json presentation.

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class ToJsonStringAspect {
    @Around("toJsonString()")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        //Object result = pjp.proceed();
        return gson.toJson(pjp.getThis());
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.tutorial.aop.*.toString(..))")
    private void toJsonString() {
    }
}
```

**main, test**

```
private void test() {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/tutorial/aop/aop.xml");

    Student student1 = (Student) context.getBean("student");
    System.out.println(student1.toString());

    Student student2 = new Student(11, "Zara");
    System.out.println(student2.toString());
}
```

**aop.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <bean id="toJsonString" class="com.tutorial.aop.ToJsonStringAspect"/>

    <bean id="student" class="com.tutorial.aop.Student">
        <property name="name"  value="Zara" />
        <property name="age"  value="11"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Result**

> //student1, intercepted
>   {   "age": 11,   "name": "Zara" }
>
> //student2, not intercepted
>   Student(age=11, name=Zara)

**Question**

How to add `student2` to bean factory programatically so student2.toString() returns json string too? where `student2` is created by some other class (e.g, returned by RestTemplate ).

**Update** 
There is a simllar issue here, even with AspectJ, you can't intercept Object.toString().
[Weaving in toString() implementation with AspectJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285591/weaving-in-tostring-implementation-with-aspectj)

Comment: Are you sure your student bean is `singleton`?

Comment: A factory produces objects, but yours was already produced. I have no idea if it is possible to convert an existing object into a Spring bean post-factum. I think you are making a simple thing complicated. When exclusively dealing with Spring beans/components, use Spring AOP. Otherwise use full AspectJ, either without Spring using compile- or load-time weaving or from inside a Spring container as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj).